# Compound Poisson Process function expected value

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

For the calculus of a financial derivatives, I need to compute the next expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}\left((\sum_{i=1}^{N_T} (J_i-k))_+\mid J_1+\cdots + J_{N_t}=x \right)$$

where $$(X_t-k)_+= \begin{cases}
             X_t-k    &   \text{if } X_t \geq k \\[6pt]
             0 &  \text{if } X_t < k
             \end{cases}
   $$

where $N_t$ is a Poisson Process, so $\sum_{i=1}^{N_T} J_i$ a compound Poisson process and $t <T$ fixed (non random). Furthermore $J_i$ are independent and identically distributed random variables and also independet of $N_t$.

Note: I think it would be a good starting point would be the next:

$$\mathbb{E}\left((\sum_{i=1}^{N_T} J_i-k))_+\mid J_1+\cdots + J_{N_t} = x \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(x+(\sum_{i=N_t}^{N_T} J_i-k)_+ \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E} \left(x+\sum_{i=N_t}^{N_T} J_i-k\mid N_T-N_t=j\right)_+\right) =\mathbb{P}(N_T-N_t=j)(\mathbb{E}(\left(x+\sum_{i=1}^j J_i-k\right)_+ = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] \frac{e^{-\lambda \tau}(\lambda \tau)^n}{n!} $$
Where,
$$\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] =\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -(k-x)\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right]= \mathbb{E} (\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -(k-x))\mathbb{E}(1_{S_n \geq k-x})=(\mathbb{E} (\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i)-k+x)\mathbb{P}(S_n \geq k-x)=(n\mathbb{E}(J_1)-k+x)(\mathbb{P}(S_n \geq k-x))$$

Comment: Are you not given the distribution of the jumps?

Comment: No, I have to do for any distribution. However, if I obtain for example for the exponential jump distribution, it would be fine.

Comment: and btw, should it actually be 
$$
E \left( (\sum^{N_T}_{i=1} J_i - k)_+ \mid J_1 + \cdots J_{N_t} = x  \right)
$$
instead of
$$
E \left( \sum^{N_T}_{i=1} (J_i - k) \mid J_1 + \cdots J_{N_t} = x  \right)_+
$$
? Because as it is now, you are subtracting the strike $k$ from each jump

Comment: Yes, you are completely ritght :)

Comment: @Slungpue Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Are $t$ and $T$ supposed to be fixed, i.e. non-random? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes! Sure! I have specified know

Answer (score 1):

Denote $J_1 + \cdots J_{N_t}$ by $S_{N_t}$.
$$
\mathbb E \left[ \left( \sum^{N_T}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+  \mid  S_{N_t}=x \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \left( \sum^{N_t}_{i=1}J_i + \sum^{N_T}_{i=N_t+1}J_i -k\right)^+  \mid  S_{N_t}=x \right]\\
=\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{N_T}_{i=N_t+1}J_i -k\right)^+  \mid  S_{N_t}=x \right]\\
=\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{N_{T-t}}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right]
$$
where the last line follows by independence of the jumps and independent/stationary increments of the Poisson process. Now condition on the no. of jumps in the interval $[0, T-t]$:
$$
 = \mathbb E \left[ \mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{N_{T-t}}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \mid  N_{T-t} = n \right]\right]\\
 = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right]\mathbb P(N_{T-t} = n) \\
= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] \frac{e^{-\lambda \tau}(\lambda \tau)^n}{n!}
$$
where $\tau = T-t$ and $\lambda$ is the intensity of the jumps . So now it remains to caluclate the expectation, which will depend on the distribution of the jumps:
$$
\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -(k-x)\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right]\\
=\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] - (k-x)\mathbb P \left( S_n \geq  k-x \right)
$$
If for example $J_i \sim \mathcal N (\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $S_n \sim \mathcal N (n\mu, n\sigma^2)$ so in particlar
$$
\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] = \int_{k-x}^\infty u \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\sigma} \exp \left( \frac{(u-n \mu)^2}{2n\sigma^2} \right) du
$$
As you can see, inserting this expectation into the infinite series and then evaluate the series will not exactly be trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot Slungpue! It is what I have written, obviosly better explicated and fixing my error (x is summing and not multiplying). But how can I continue in that point?

Comment: @Edin_91 you will have to find the distribution of the random variable $Y_n = \sum^n J_j$ and calculate $E[(Y_n-(k-x))^+]$ and then plug this into the infinite series. But if $J_i$ is for example Normally distributed you're not gonna get a closed-form expression (as far as I know). So what to do next highly depends on the distribution of the jumps. May I ask where this problem is from? Is it an exercise from a book or something else?

Comment: Is it okay   the part that I have completed in my answer? it can´t be developed more?

Comment: @Edin_91 I added some lines for demonstration. Your derivation beyond what I wrote is wrong, unfortunately. The expectation of the product in not a product of the expectations, as the random variables are not independent.

Comment: @ Slungpue It wouldn´t be, $$\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] = \int_{k-x}^\infty u \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi n}} \exp \left( \frac{(x-n \mu)^2}{2n\sigma^2} \right) du$$ And, $$\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -(k-x)\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right]\\
=\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] - (k-x)\mathbb P \left( S_n \geq  k-x \right)$$

Comment: You are right! They are not independent because, $\sum_{i=1}^n{J_i}$ and $S_n$ depend both of $J_i$. Correct?

Comment: @Edin_91 well, yes, since I defined $\sum^n J_i  = S_n$

Comment: Well for so any  distribution of $J_i$ we have that $$\mathbb E \left[ \left( x + \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -k\right)^+ \right] = \mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i -(k-x)\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right]\\
=\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] - (k-x)\mathbb P \left( S_n \geq  k-x \right)$$ where, $S_n = \sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i$ and hence, $$\mathbb{E} (\sum_{i=1}^n J_i 1_{S_n \geq k-x})=\int_{k-x}^{\infty}f_{J}^{n)}(y^n) y^n 1_{y^n \geq k-x}dy^n$$ where $f_{J}^{n)}$ is the n-th convolution of the $J_i$

Comment: And $$\mathbb{P}(S_n \geq k-x)=\int_{k-x}^{\infty}f_{J}^{n)}(y^n) dy^n$$

Comment: @ Slungpue So, all in all $$\mathbb E \left[ \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}J_i\right) 1_{S_n \geq k-x} \right] - (k-x)\mathbb P \left( S_n \geq  k-x \right)=\int_{k-x}^{\infty}f_{J}^{n)}(y^n) (y^n  -k+x) 1_{y^n \geq k-x}dy^n$$